# Update Query Intermittently Slow on PostgreSQL Database

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update

I've noticed all my queries including the following one seem to be fast most of the time, but will randomly be slow and I'm not sure why.

I've been trying to track down the cause, so I added auto_explain and it just logged the following query

```sql
START TRANSACTION
UPDATE "recipes" SET "servings" = $2, "updatedAt" = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP 
WHERE "id" IN ($1) RETURNING "updatedAt"
COMMIT
```

```
    Update on public.recipes  (cost=0.29..8.30 rows=1 width=1599) (actual time=312.687..312.693 rows=1 loops=1)
      Buffers: shared hit=122 read=2 dirtied=4
      ->  Index Scan using recipes_uid_key on public.recipes  (cost=0.29..8.30 rows=1 width=1599) (actual time=0.019..0.023 rows=1 loops=1)
            Index Cond: (recipes.id = '5f6d6875-2d32-4306-bf41-7ba541f23592'::uuid)
            Buffers: shared hit=3
```

I found it odd that it jumped from `8.30` to `312.687` for actual time and didn't explain where that time went. Does anyone know what this means? Maybe the rows were locked and it was waiting for it to be unlocked?

Table size: 15K records

Comment: Looks like `id` is a primary key. You'd need heavy traffic for row locking to be factor IMO. Is anyone doing DDL (ALTER TABLE type things?) Or maybe a session with commit off where you're not committing / rolling back?

Comment: Could it be that one query with a large numbers of ids in the `IN` clause is running while another session is trying to update the same or partially the same records? I guess this could put the second query on hold until the first one finishes and explain the delay

Comment: when the query is slow is there any other update/insert query executing on the same table.

Comment: Off-topic: to avoid idempotent updates, you could add `"servings" IS DISTINCT FROM  $2` to the WHERE CLAUSE

Comment: @dassum I'm only logging things in postgresql that take longer than 30ms, but there are 2 selects on the table right before and some datadog queries 4 seconds later (I use datadog to monitor postgres)

Comment: @wildplasser so is that in case the same update query is running multiple times?

Comment: @RobertBain I do have low traffic and no sessions with commit off that I'm aware of.  Is there a way for me to double check that?

Comment: @benawad No, just to avoid disk traffic if the value is not actually changed.

Comment: @wildplasser is that always worth adding to updates? Is it still good if I'm updating multiple fields?

Comment: It is always cheaper. Wich multiple fields, you'd have to check if ANY of them actually changes. With postgres the win can be large, because you avoid creating multiple row versions, which will need to be vacuumd out later.

Comment: The number of shared buffer hits is suspiciously large for a single-row update.  Although being hits rather than reads, they shouldn't be very time consuming.  But you should turn on track_io_timing anyway, just in case it shows something useful.

Comment: What version of PostgreSQL are you running?

Comment: @jjanes thanks, I'll add track_io_timing. I'm on version 11.2

Answer (score 0):

One cause of slow random access via index would be if the required data was not cached and the disks would have to perform several seek operations to get it. However this query takes 300ms, that's a lot of seeks, especially if the disk is a SSD. So I don't think this is the case unless this is a really huge table with large rows and maybe lots of TOAST data.

Besides the usual: Vacuum, or even CLUSTER if you have a meaningful index to cluster on...

I'd suspect a lock issue. There could be another transaction executing concurrently with your query that updates the same row, then takes a while before issuing a COMMIT. It could be a transaction that updates several rows, or a lock due to foreign keys, etc.

You can comb through your queries manually looking for a culprit, or do a query on [pg_locks](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/view-pg-locks.html) before this slow update you're trying to debug to list any locks on the "recipes" table. Then perform the update and time it, and if it was slow then log the result of the locks query. You have to check locks before executing the update though. If you do the update first and then check for locks, any lock that the update waited on will have been released by the time the update is finished, so the culprit will no longer be in pg_locks.

Comment: I added
`log_lock_waits = true` and `deadlock_timeout = 50`
to my config to catch any locks next time

Comment: Good hunting then!

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was related to GIN index and its fastupdate mechanism, here you'll find more details on this https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/286812

Also found an article with a deep dive on this issue https://iamsafts.com/posts/postgres-gin-performance/

Answer (score -1):

This situation happens if there are some usually massive queries or even multiple number of them working on the same small table that frequently updates (Or even in the same database NOT on the same table). You can try to avoid running these queries if it is possible and let `AUTOVACUUM` do his job or try to make your table lighter by removing unnecessary versions from it by yourself.

Try

```
VACUUM FULL recipes;
```

`VACUUM` reclaims storage occupied by dead tuples. `VACUUM FULL` gets exclusive lock on the table, but sometimes other competing queries won't release lock since they may require access to dead tuples. 
If `VACUUM FULL` doesn't help, the possible solution can be creating some kind of custom `VACUUM`. [More on vacuum](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/sql-vacuum.html)

```
    VACUUM recipes;
BEGIN TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE; 
  SET LOCAL statement_timeout = '1s'; SET LOCAL lock_timeout = '1s'; 
  --we got exception if we can't get this table exclusively locked in 1 second (for stopping this transaction from over waiting of exclusive lock)
  LOCK TABLE recipes IN ACCESS EXCLUSIVE MODE; 
  --2 rows above to lock table exclusively for this transaction
  CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp ON COMMIT DROP AS TABLE recipes;
  TRUNCATE TABLE recipes;
  INSERT INTO recipes TABLE temp;
COMMIT;
```

More on this particular case can be found on [habr](https://habr.com/en/post/481866/)

Comment: Do you still think this is the case if the table has 15K record and I don't  have massive queries?

Comment: I still think it can be an issue. At least worth trying.

Comment: ok, I'll give it a try. Do I need to do anything to setup autovacuum?

Comment: Autovacuum is already enabled. You can enable it manually by ALTER TABLE x SET (autovacuum_enabled = on). The trick is to use manual vacuum and custom VACUUM FULL

Comment: How do you know when you should run vacuum manually? Just when you spot a slow query?

Comment: I am not very certain it will help. When it is something that suggests multiple queries on indexes of tables that are often updated.